# How to Resolve PKIX path building failed on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ssl, server

I develop and distribute plugins.

I confirmed that there was a problem in plugin when installing the plugin in Eclipse.

problem detail : PKIX path building failed. sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException : unable to find valid certification path to requested targe

The detailed situation is as follows.

1. 1 Years Ago, I applied ssl certificate to updatesite.
2. The certificate has expired and the certificate has been replaced.
3. The update site can be accessed from browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.) and it has been confirmed that the certificate is valid.
4. But when I enter the url in Eclipse > Help > Install New Software I get a PKIX error.

So, when I checked, I found that the Fingerprint of Hostname displayed in Eclipse > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2 > Known hosts was different.

So, even if I delete the corresponding value and apply it, the previous information is loaded again.

So it looked like the jvm was still loading.

To solve it, you can enter the following command when running it in Eclipse.

```
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore='certification path'
```

However, this is only a workaround for users, you cannot use this workaround as a distributor.

What settings should I make on the server?

For reference, it worked fine when applying the SSL certificate for the first time, but it didn't work after replacing it. Also, fortunately, thanks to backing up the previous certificate, the plug-in download from the update site works well after restoring it. (About 1 month left until the previous certificate)